# Close terminal window after using xterm

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, xterm

I have the following code

```
xterm -e <some command>  & 
<line 2 command>
```

Now after the line 2 command I want the close the xterm -e  window automated.

How can I close the terminal window that I opened in the my script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get **PID** of the last background task lauched with **$!**, and then **kill** it after your *line 2 command* is achived.

```
xterm -e <some command>  &
myBackgroundXtermPID=$!
<line 2 command>
kill $myBackgroundXtermPID
```

I assume that if your background process ends before *line 2* , its PID will not be reused by another process (if you run out of PID numbers).

Comment: Thanks  that is very  helpful